# How can I store 1000 as a * to be displayed on a graph?

Tags: c++

I am working a a school project (C++) and I have read and read and cant find out how to do this. I have to import numbers from a file those numbers are going to be rounded to the nearest 1000 for simplicity. I can call all those no problem where my problem lye's is once I have that data i have to display a little bar graph where * represents every 1000.
I think I am going to have to divide by 1000 once i have imported the data into a var and some how take the quotient and out put a * for each one. can you point me in the right direction?

displayed kinda like this:

```
5000 *****
1000 *
3000 ***
```

Comment: What have you tried and doesn't work? I think you'll have an easier time understanding what you really need than us.

Comment: Just divide each number by 1000, do a cast to ```int``` and loop through assembling a string with the proper amount of asterisks to print out.

Comment: I am going to Try casting to int and looping ill be back if no success

Comment: @user3268048 Is it really **that hard**, to show the relevant code here??

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a simple loop:

```
int value = ...; // 5000, 1000, 3000, etc
std::cout << value;

int num = value / 1000;
if (num > 0)
{
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        std::cout << '*';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```